# PHP stristr issue

Tags: php

```
$bodytext = "we should see this text <more> but not this at all <html>";
if(stristr($bodytext, "<more>") == TRUE)
{
    $find = "<more>";
    $pos = stripos($bodytext, $find);
    $bodytext = substr($bodytext, 0, $pos);
}
echo "$bodytext";
```

If the $bodytext contains other html code, this also causes the above code to return true :

```
<more
more>
```

How do I adjust my code so only (and exactly) :

```
<more>
```

returns true?

Answer (score 2):

Simple/naiive:

```
$bodytext = preg_replace('/(.*?)<more>.*/', $1, $bodytext);
```

Answer (score 2):

[stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) returns all of the string from the match to the end of the string.  If a match is not found, it returns false.

You therefore need to do this:

```
if(stristr($bodytext, "<more>") !== false) {
    // match found
}
```

[stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) is more suited to your needs:

```
$pos = stripos($bodytext, "<more>"); 
if($pos !== false) {
    // match found
}
```

**Alternative:** See Marc B's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167338/php-stristr-issue/#answer-7167455), which does everything you appear to be trying to achieve in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the explode function and output the first element of the array

```
$bodytext = "we should see this text <more> but not this at all <html>";
if(stristr($bodytext, "<more>") == TRUE)
{
$split = explode('<more>', $bodytext);
echo $split[0];
}
```